# How does one add a collaborator in GitLab using the command line?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-api

I am trying to achieve a task of creating multiple repositories(around 300-400) and each repositories is assigned to only 1 user/collaborator. Can this be automated via command line instructions or GitLab APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could automate this using Gitlabs [API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/).
Assuming you know the members ids beforehand: You can use the [Group and project members API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/members.html#add-a-member-to-a-group-or-project) or directly [create a project for a specific user](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#create-project-for-user). You need to be the admin of the group above or global admin to call these.